# PHP compare time variables with if/else

Tags: php, if-statement, timestamp, strtotime

I am trying to echo some text depending on the results of a timestamp, using an `if/else` statement.

My logic is as follows;

Based on the value of `$data`;

- If no results => echo '*no results*'
- If date is **less than** todays date => echo '*expired*'
- Else => echo '*active*'

The problem I am facing is that currently my code always displays 'active' no matter what the date is - my code so far is;

```
<?php

$data = get_patronapi_data($id);//this contains a date in the format 31-12-13

$dataTimestamp = strtotime($data);//convert date to timestamp
$now = strtotime('today');set timestamo for $now

//echo strtotime('now'); this outputs 1446820684 
//echo $dataTimestamp; this outputs 1954886400
//echo $data; this outputs 31-12-13

//if $data is empty
if (empty($data)){
    echo 'no results';
}
//if $data is not empty but date is less than today
elseif (!empty($data) && $dataTimestamp < $now) {
    echo 'expired date is' .$date; //in d-m-y format
}
//everything else
else {
    echo 'active date is ' .$date; //in d-m-y format
}
?>
```

I'm sure the answer will be obvious to a pro but you have a newbie here!

Comment: tip: `strtotime('today')` is a waste of cpu time. just do `$now = time()`.

Comment: and have you checked what values are in `$datatimestamp`. If strtotime fails, it returns boolean false, which will be treated as integer `0` for your `<` testing.

Comment: adjust `get_patronapi_data()` to return `2013-12-31` instead of `31-12-13`

Comment: Doesn't `strtotime('today')` equal the start of the day?  Do you need it to be the current second, or the start of the day?

Comment: Because `strtotime` did not know what is the year in you impl. When you use "-" it expects the american format you can also replace the "-" with "." like `31.12.13`. Them strtotime expect german (etc) format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
function myDateToTs($date){
    $data_array = explode("-",$date);
    return strtotime('20'.$data_array[2].'-'.$data_array[1].'-'.$data_array[0]);
}

$data = "31-12-13";      
$dataTimestamp = myDateToTs($data);
$now = strtotime('today');

//echo strtotime('now'); this outputs 1446820684
//echo $dataTimestamp; this outputs 1954886400
//echo $data; this outputs 31-12-13

//if $data is empty
if (empty($data)){
echo 'no results';
}
//if $data is not empty but date is less than today
elseif (!empty($data) && $dataTimestamp < $now) {
echo 'expired';
}
//everything else
else {
echo 'active';
}
```

Comment: it's just about converting `31-12-13` to `2013-12-13`. `explode` will split the $data sting to an array like `array('31','12','13')`. Them i use this array to build a new string (where the array helps to swap the order of the numbers): `$data = '20'.$data_array[2].'-'.$data_array[1].'-'.$data_array[0];`

Comment: no that's all. you could make a function for it (i will change my post to show)

Comment: +1 for the explanation and function, thanks Phillip - I would never have got there on my own! All working as expected now! Would it be very difficult to add the functionality 'Expired x number of days ago?' Pushing my luck now I know! :)

Answer (score 0):

date format dd-mm-yy format is not valid for strtime

Try

> American month, day and year  mm "/" dd "/" y "12/22/78", "1/17/2006",
>   "1/17/6"

or

> Day, month and four digit year, with dots, tabs or dashes dd [.\t-] mm
>   [.-] YY   "30-6-2008", "22.12\t1978"
>
> Day, month and two digit year, with
>   dots or tabs  dd [.\t] mm "." yy  "30.6.08", "22\t12\t78"

http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php